# Allowing Ubuntu user on ec2 to upload and manage files in public web folder

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ssh, root, amazon-ec2

Just created a new ec2 ubuntu instance, and i'm forced to login as `ubuntu` rather `root`.

While Its ok as of standard security practice but it creates additional problems that `ubuntu` user cannot upload &/or manage files in any directory except its `/home/ubuntu`. :-(

Is there a way to allow ubuntu to upload & edit files everywhere while keeping ownership to root.  I prefer straight uploading to destination with filezilla, rather copying from my `/home/ubuntu/` to `/anylocation/` via ssh)

For example a use case: in /var/www/  `ubuntu` will be able to upload the files & edit them but file ownership is still owned by root.

I would also like it be able to edit `/etc/` directory for ferquent changes in php & apache config files etc. (keeping the file ownership unchanged)